# Clone MySQL with dump->import or replicator

Tags: database-connection, mysql, mysql-backup

I have a LAMP (CentOS) serving about 100 normal CMS (mostly Joomla) sites. I have rsync on the files, but I would also like to backup the databases to another server **offsite**.

I've been reading and what i understand you can either dump the databases on the main server, rsync the dumps and then import them on the backup server. The other option is to use MySQL's own Replicator.

The replicator looks very nice, but in all the examples I read both the master and slave seems to be on the same LAN. How will this work when you want to replicate offsite, over a 10mbps connection? Is this process really heavy? Is it better to run a normal dump->import script once every night?

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you want to have a second server offsite? If you just want a backup then use MySQLDump (or one of the many equivalents) and dump it somewhere safe (offsite). If you want a replicated host for some other use then MySQL just needs a few open ports between the two hosts. The connection speed required is contingent on how much data is being updated on the master. If you don't update much or are okay with the slave being laggy then its ok for it to be a tad slow. Its easy enough to test and see.

Once you get the initial copy of the data on the slave, the binlogs just contain changes. Do you have a sense of how much data is being changed on the master currently?

Comment: From the beginning I just wanted to backup the data, but when I thought about it I came up with the idea that the backup server might also work as a secondary clone, so if the main server goes down I can change the A record to the slave. Nightly dumps would be enough for this, and when the maaster goes up again I don't see the need to have the slave pushing back all the changes to the master.

I don't know how much data I use. But it's around 100 databases and every db is about 3mb. It's mostly normal CMS with reads, but there's a few webshops that generates orders etc.

Comment: Sounds like pretty low traffic and pretty small data so you'd probably be ok. And since its all CMS stuff it won't matter if your slave lags a bit.

Answer (score 0):

If you've got a lot of data that doesn't change (and I'd imagine your CMS data is a many-read, few-writes scenario), then replication would result in less overall traffic.

Replication requires that the master executes all transactions against the slave, whereas a nightly dump/rebuild requires that you transfer all data nightly (unless you've got a more complex incremental backup solution, or perhaps you stop your replication and only start the slave at night; also a complex solution).

Because replication sends transactions across the network, you'll find that it doesn't use lots of bandwidth unless you're firing BLOBs around, and again, in a CMS that's probably not likely.

Replication is harder to set up than a nightly dump/rebuild, and needs to be managed more carefully. On the other hand, backups benefit from downtime, which is becoming less and less available on the web...

Answer (score 0):

Setup a slave using innobackupex (http://www.percona.com/software/percona-xtrabackup/). 300-400 mb will backup in minutes. It's a hot backup that does not need the master to be locked or shut down.

You could even use DRBD-backed storage to a secondary location.